# Is it a good idea to use Wicket with GWT widgets?

Tags: gwt, wicket, integration

In the past I have worked a lot with GWT and GXT and I'm rather new at Wicket.

We want to have widgets in an existing Wicket application. 
These widgets are completely stand-alone "applications". Would GWT be a good solution to do this?

Also we use a lot of Ajax requests (in the current widgets) to update / retrieve data. Since I found that GWT handles those ajax requests very nicely with RPC mechanism I thought it might be a good idea.

Comment: You can embed GWT widgets into a Wicket page just like any javascript component. Tight integration (sharing infrastructure and/or request processing cycle) would take a little more work, though. Sorry, the question is a little too vague to have a clear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used GWT and Wicket in a moderately complicated environment. The integration is pretty smooth as long as you use JavaScript for any of your integration points. Make sure you setOutputMarkupId on components that you need to update from the GWT end of things and you’ll be set.

Whether it’s a good idea or not is completely dependent on your team and project. I used it to integrate an older drag & drop tool into our new wicket based application. It worked well as a stopgap until we redesign the GWT app using wicket + jquery.